# How do you deal with memory management and signal/slots?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I have an object which emits a signal with an object:

```
MyObj *obj = this->generateObj();
emit newObjSignal(obj);
delete obj;
```

and I have one or more people who connect to this. The problem is that the delete call gets called before the objects receive the signal. How do I deal with this?

Comment: in Qt, the signal/slot mechanism is synchronous by default (i.e. no problem since all slots are already called when delete is called), unless you are signalling across threads (or you explicitly specify a delayed connection policy). If you are indeed signalling across threads, you have to be careful about using the smart pointer solutions as they may not be thread safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **smart pointers**, so that memory management will be handled automatically and you will be sure you will have:

1. No dangling pointers;
2. No memory leaks.

In this case, it seems to me `std::shared_ptr<>` (or `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` or `boost::shared_ptr<>` if you are not working with C++11) is the correct choice:

```
#include <memory> // For std::shared_ptr<>
// ...
std::shared_ptr<MyObj> obj(this->generateObj());
emit_new_signal(obj);
// delete obj; // <== No need for this anymore!
```

Also notice, that the handler functions will have to accept a `std::shared_ptr<MyObj>` rather than a raw pointer `MyObj*`, but the code inside those handlers won't have to be changed, because `std::shared_ptr` provides an overload of `operator ->`.

Notice that, in general, the use of `new` is discouraged in C++11, and when possible one should use `std::make_shared<>` to create `shared_ptr`s. Thererfore, you may want to rewrite your `generateObj()` member function so that it returns an `std::shared_ptr<MyObj>` instead of a `MyObj*`, and let it use `std::make_shared<MyObj>()` internally to instantiate the object.

**NOTE:**

As pointed out by [Geier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192139/geier) in the comments, Qt has its own smart pointer class [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html) that you may want to use.

Comment: Qt also has its own shared pointers like [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html)

Comment: @Geier: OK, I am not familiar with Qt, but I will add this info to my answer. Thank you for that

Comment: What do you do for objects (i.e. malloc'ed structs) that you get from c?

Comment: @chacham15: In that case you could use `std::shared_ptr<>` with a custom deleter. You can specify a custom deleter as the second argument  to the constructor of `std::shared_ptr`, after the raw pointer to the object being wrapped (note, that this is not possible with `std::make_shared()`). Your custom deleter could then invoke `free()`.

Comment: Is it possible to use unique_ptr in this case?

Answer (score 4):

While you can use a `QSharedPointer`, another approach is to not use dynamic memory allocation. The code would therefore be -

```
MyObj obj = this->generateObj();
emit newObjSignal(obj);
```

This will obviously result in copies of `MyObj` being created. Qt generally solves this issue by using [implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html) or copy-on-write.

In order for your own class to use this implicit sharing mechanism you will have to change the structure of your class and use [`QSharedData`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddata.html) and [`QSharedDataPointer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddatapointer.html)

```
class MyObjData : public QSharedData {
public:
    int variable;
};

class MyObj {
    MyObj() : d(new MyObjData) {}
    int foo() { return d->variable; }
private:
    QSharedDataPointer<MyObjData> d;
};
```

This way copies of `MyObj` would be very cheap and you can easily pass it over a signal.

This is IMO a lot cleaner than using a QSharedPointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just emit another signal in the slot where the signal "newObjSignal(obj)" is consumed then call deletelater.

`connect(someobject,SIGNAL(finish()),obj,SLOT(deleteLater()));`